# Не пишет текст в сервисе wireframe

Tags: веб-программирование

Подскажите пожалуйста
В сервисе wireframe выделяю прямоугольник , начинаю писать но он исчезает, подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть проблема

Comment: В этот вопрос следует включить больше подробностей и уточнить проблему.

Comment: После выделения прямоугольника кликаю по значку "А" для написания текста.
После начинаю писать . но он мгновенно затирается , пробовал вырезать-вставить, не помогает

Answer (score -2):

В браузере яндекс отключил переводчик страниц, все заработало.